# Using Bulk Insert to import a csv file without specifying column names?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

When creating a table before the bulk insert, is there a way to NOT specify the column names and use whatever column names are on the csv file?  I have some columns in my csv file that are quarters, like 2012Q2, 2012Q3, etc.  In the future, these are going to change depending on the time and that's why I don't want to specify the column names.  If this is possible, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: There's not quite enough information here to answer your question. Are you creating the table each time you import the CSV? What are you using to import it?

Comment: @JeffSiver Yes I'm creating it every time so if it exists, it is being dropped and created again.  I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 and I wanted to use BULK INSERT to import my csv file.

Comment: I'll have to check (it's been a while) but I thought SSMS has an option when importing an CSV to use the first row as column names.

Comment: @JeffSiver I can do that when importing via SQL Server Import and Export Wizard but I don't want to do that. I'm trying to automate something so I want to use T-SQL code.

Comment: Sorry but I don't believe the TSQL bulk import operations allow you to dynamically define the table. You can save the SQL Server Import Wizard as an SSIS package which could be run as needed.

Answer (score -1):

One way to this is:

1. Drop the table on BigQuery
2. Get column names from your CSV
3. Create table using the column names from your CSV.
   PHP example can be found here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/api/src/functions/create_table.php
   (the fields = your column names)
4. Import the CSV

Done!